# Tab completion in zsh makes duplicate characters

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, tty, oh-my-zsh

when using tab completion in zsh, using ohmyzsh, in a relatively fresh arch install, the first two characters will duplicate themselves and become not deletable.

For instance, I type `yay -S terminato` , then hit tab to autocomplete to terminator right? It works fine, and i can tab through the results as usual, but the beginning of the line, instead of being `yay -S term...` is instead `yayay -S term...`

When i hit backspace, so as to correct the error, i found that i could not delete past the `yay` , leaving me with a `ya` at the very start that i couldn't remove.

This is only for the single line, and it doesn't actually affect anything, the command will still execute properly, even with the two characters that don't belong.

Ive tried other emulators, but the issue persists, even in a base tty.

hitting enter, or ctrl c to move to the next line resets that new line, but the old line remains with its dangling characters.

to be clear, this happens with all commands with tab completion, not just yay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means some kind of error has been printed, but then the command line got repainted on top of the error, albeit in slightly the wrong place, because of the characters printed by the error message.

The reason you cannot delete the first `ya` is because it is part of the old command line that got printed over. It's not actually part of your new command line, so you cannot edit it. In other words, there are characters printed in your terminal that failed to get erased, and your shell knows nothing about them.

To get to the bottom of this error, do

```bash
set -vx
```

then try the same completion again and see if you can spot any error message somewhere in the output.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem which manifested similarly. I traced the problem to the value of `LC_ALL`. I stopped exporting `LC_ALL` (and friends) as `C` and exported `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and the problem went away.

I bisected the problem down to Zsh, in tmux, in **one particular oh-my-zsh theme**. (`robbeyrussell` was the first creator of oh-my-zsh I think, so the breadcrumbs now lead to the "official" GitHub organization)

- https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/3368

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995089/lang-environment-variable-in-zsh
- List item

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It was indeed connected with locale settings as mentioned above.

I have solved it by regenerating the locale.

```
sudo echo en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 > /etc/locale.gen
sudo locale-gen
```

After restarting it started to work normally.